CDI Custom Scope not working with WELD-001303 error
I have Jetty project (Jetty embedded based version 11) with JPA, CDI, JMS & JAX-RS project.
Everything works good, however I want to add a new scope
@Inherited
@NormalScope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyScoped {}

I have also the context of the scope
import jakarta.enterprise.context.spi.Context;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.spi.Contextual;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class MyScopeContext implements Context {

    private final Map<Bean<?>, Object> instances = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final BeanManager beanManager;

    public MyScopeContext(BeanManager beanManager) {
        this.beanManager = beanManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> getScope() {
        return MyScoped.class;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T get(Contextual<T> contextual, CreationalContext<T> creationalContext) {
        System.out.println("FLAG1");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) contextual;
        return (T) instances.computeIfAbsent(bean, b -> beanManager.getContext(bean.getScope()).get(bean, creationalContext));
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T get(Contextual<T> contextual) {
        System.out.println("FLAG2");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) contextual;
        return (T) instances.get(bean);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isActive() {
        return true
    }

    // Method to clean up instances when the context is destroyed
    public void destroy() {
        instances.clear();
    }

}
I've activate the context hard coded to make it work.
And this is the Extension:
import jakarta.enterprise.event.Observes;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.*;

public class MyScopeExtension implements Extension {

    void afterBeanDiscovery(@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery abd, BeanManager manager) {
        BeanManager beanManager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
        abd.addContext(new MyScopeContext(beanManager));
    }

    void addScope(@Observes final BeforeBeanDiscovery beforeBeanDiscovery) {
        beforeBeanDiscovery.addScope(MyScoped.class, true, false);
    }

        BeanManager beanManager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
        afterBeanDiscovery.addContext(new MyScopeContext(beanManager));
    }
}

I have also simple bean to demonstrate it all together:
@MyScoped
public class TempBean {
    public String say() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}

Final step, I added the file jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension in resources/META-INF/services with the content io.shaikezam.scope.MyScopeExtension
Now, when I build the and run the project I get:
org.jboss.weld.contexts.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type io.shaikezam.scope.MyScoped
I can see that the jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension file in the builded jar is in classes/META-INF/services/ and not in META-INF/services/, maybe it's related?
The is the pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.shaikezam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta-system-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>product-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-cdi2-se</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jms-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.shaikezam</groupId>
            <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>


If you misplace META-INF/services entry, the extension will not be discovered and executed - you can easily try by either debugging the code in the extension or putting some system out prints in there.
Assuming your deployment is a WAR and the extension code resides under WEB_INF/classes/packageNames/... then the service file should be under WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services

The final artifact is JAR (embedded jetty). I add prints but nothing showed, probably the extension file isn't in the right place?

Seems like it, you should have it just under META-INF/services inside the JAR.

For some reason it's under classes/META-INF/services/, any idea why is it?
